# Ethereum Mining Hashrates fluctuate wildly

Tags: ether, mining, mining-pools, hashrate

[image: Hashrate]

Hi, I've just set up a new rig and I'm having very variable hash rates, which I don't think are normal?

System:
* GIGABYTE GA-B250M-DS3H Motherboard
* DUAL Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB x2

Running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.10.0-28-generic x86_64)

One thing, I set up the machine and then unplugged the monitor, peripherals. I connected the GPUs afterwards, because when I connected the GPUs the monitor wouldn't show anything either on the motherboard HDMI port or on the new GPU ports.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient disk space can cause large fluctuations. For example after Windows updates.